# How to find list of files in changeset(Clearcase UCM) which are not delivered?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool, clearcase-ucm

In Clearcase UCM When we are delivering an activity to integration stream, it list all the files to be delivered. But is there any way to find the list alone instead of doing real delivery?

If i look into change set it has all the files which were delivered previously.

Is there any way to do mock- delivery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides VonC's answer, I can suggest another two resolutions:

a. `cleartool deliver -preview`

b. Based on a ClearCase add-on we provide, "**[R&D Reporter](http://gomidjets.com/rnd.php?s=stackoverflow2)**", you can get a report of "Pending Changes". You can compare two streams (or more) and get a report of all differences, one way or two ways. If you run it on integration stream and its child stream, you get exactly what you want, directly into Excel sheet or email. You can also filter out unnecessary stuff like delivery/rebase activities and more.

Answer (score 1):

Considering a deliver is a simple merge, you can use [`findmerge`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_findmerge.htm)

```
 cleartool findmerge -fversion .../StreamName/LATEST -print
```

> If you specify `–print` as the action (and you do not also specify any of the merge actions), findmerge does not actually perform any merges. Instead, it shows what merge activity would be required.

If you perform that command in the destination view (on the Integration Stream), you can find what version (from the source Stream) needs merging.